# White Status bar when using [application setStatusBarHidden:YES] (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, user-interface, interface, sdk

I'm trying to hide the status bar, but once I hide it, its replace by a white bar instead.

The view is landscape.

I want it so the status bar has completely disappeared.

Here is the code in the delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hide it on launch, just hide it in your info.plist using [UIStatusBarHidden](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW15). This assumes you never want it in your app.

Then make sure your view controllers are all set to "wants full screen".

Comment: That's between you and your nib file. Have you got the status bar visible in there? Are you ever showing the status bar?

Comment: No the status bar as shown as 'none', the view is just showing.